# How to let scroll events through an overlay but not click events

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, html5-canvas

I would like to create a map annotation tool with custom controls (not using map providers built-in annotation features).

Something like this:

[image]

My idea was to overlay a canvas above the map.

The problem is: I can't zoom on the map by scrolling anymore because of that overlay.

And if I set `pointer-events: none` to the canvas, then I can't draw on the canvas anymore.

Demo: https://codepen.io/vandrieu/pen/qBqdpzX?editors=1010

I would like to be able to draw on the canvas while still being able to zoom the map by scrolling the mouse.

How would you do this?

Comment: I would say just create a button to switch between movement and drawing.

Comment: You could add a `scroll` event to the canvas which sends the [`scroll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scroll) to the map.

Comment: @Rojo could you give me a hint about how to send events to another element? I have no idea how to do that.

Comment: @Rojo PS: I found how. Using event dispatching. Unfortunately, sending the `wheel` event to the map element does not work. The map does not zoom.

Comment: @Rojo I made it work and it's thanks to you. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Rojo's comment I started looking into event dispatching and wrote this method that dispatches an event to another

```
function redirectEvent(eventType, fromElementSelector, toElementSelector) {
  const fromElement=document.querySelector(fromElementSelector)
  const toElement=document.querySelector(toElementSelector)
  fromElement.addEventListener(eventType, function (event) {
    toElement.dispatchEvent(new event.constructor(event.type, event));
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    //event.stopImmediatePropagation();
  });
}
```

Then I struggled,

First because `scroll` event didn't work. Until I figured out the right event for this is not `scroll`, it's `wheel`.

Then because dispatching the event this way:
`redirectEvent("wheel", '#canvas2', '#map2')`
Didn't work.
I figured maybe I needed to send the event to the canvas inside the map (the map is rendered using a canvas).

So I changed to:
`redirectEvent("wheel", '#canvas2', '#map2 canvas')`
But it didn't work either.

The reason is when page loads, the canvas inside the map is not rendered yet.

But if I wait a little:

```
setTimeout(() => {
redirectEvent("wheel", '#canvas2', '#map2 canvas')   
},2000)
```

It works!

See the updated demo (map number 2): https://codepen.io/vandrieu/pen/qBqdpzX?editors=1010